# Passing cv:Mat from android to jni

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to send a Mat object from android side to jni side, i do not want to send mat object address.
But my jni code returns 0 for no of rows in Mat, which i'm not getting.

Android-Java code is :

```
buttton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);
         Log.d(TAG,Integer.toString(m.rows())+" "+Integer.toString(m.cols()));

        textView.setText(Integer.toString(openCVJNI(m)));
    }
});
```

JNI code is :

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
    Java_com_example_color_MainActivity_openCVJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, Mat inputImage)
    {   
       return inputImage.rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `m` is an `org.opencv.core.Mat`, what you're getting at the C++ side is a `jobject`, not a C++ `Mat`.

Comment: so even if i receive it as jobject, how do i use it as Mat object. Is their any other way to pass a mat object.

Answer (score 11):

See https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing sample.

`org.opencv.core.Mat` has `getNativeObjAddr` method, it returns `long`, which can be interpreted as pointer to `cv::Mat`.

Java code:

```
openCVJNI(m.getNativeObjAddr());
```

JNI code:

```
Java_com_example_color_MainActivity_openCVJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, long addrInputImage)
{
    cv::Mat* pInputImage = (cv::Mat*)addrInputImage;
    return pInputImage->rows;
}
```